# Share Data Between Node App and React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, local-storage

I have two apps running on my local-dev machine:

1. Main app (Node using Express and Pug to render views) running at
   localhost:4000
2. Helper app (react build served using express) running at localhost:4001

When a user logs in, I execute the following script on the client side of the main app:

```
function() { localStorage.setItem('prefix_token', '" + token + "'); } )();
function() { console.log( localStorage.getItem('prefix_token') ); } )();
```

Which correctly outputs the correct token that is created on a successful login.

However, when I try to access localStorage on my second app (the helper app), it doesn't seem to use the same localStorage.

```
...

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("made it here")
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("prefix_token"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The output is always:

```
"made it here"
null
```

:(

How do I share the token variable from the to the helper app?

Comment: Have you tried using a cookie?

Comment: Localstorage is unique for host:port. So since your apps use different ports, they cannot access the same localstorage.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Everyone.

Cookies seem to a good avenue. 

Question is similar to referenced one in these comments. 

I'll post a working cookie version